# JavaScript counter zero on every change list of element/value (start from zero)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can you guys please help i have made almost everything, but when i change value counter should be zero (basically its a counter made from JavaScript in which when you click on the image it should
count it 1 in the counter and when i change the value on the list it should become zero like from the start)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>script</title>
</head>
<body>
    

<p>Select a AWRAD from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="Al-ASaS">الاساس</option>
  <option value="IztikFar">استغفار</option>
</select>

<p>Your Selected Awrad will be shown here.</p>

<!--Custom Div-->

<div style="width: 200px;height: 100px;border: 2px green solid;border-radius: 5px;" id="div-j">

  <h4 id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></h4>
  <p id="clicks" style="text-align: center;"></p>


</div>


<!--Custom Div Ends-->


<br>
<!--<p id="clicks"></p><br>-->

<script>

function myFunction() {

var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x ;

};

 var clicks = 0;
        function onClick() {
          clicks += 1;
          document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks; 
          };


</script>


<!--New Function-->
<script>
    function mycount() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
    </script>
    







    <script>
   //     var clicks = 0;
        
    //    function onClick() {
       //   clicks += 1;
      //    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
   //     };
        </script>
        
        <img src="https://mb.burhaniya.pk/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/counter.png" onClick="onClick()" width="70" height="70" />
        <!--<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>-->




        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set the clicks to 0 when the select dropdown is used and rerender them.

```js
var clicks = 0;

// extracted this for DRYness
function displayClicks() {
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}

function onSelect() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  // simply reset the clicks and rerender them
  clicks = 0;
  displayClicks();
};


function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  displayClicks();
};

function mycount() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>script</title>
</head>

<body>


  <p>Select a AWRAD from the list.</p>

  <select id="mySelect" onchange="onSelect()">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Al-ASaS">الاساس</option>
    <option value="IztikFar">استغفار</option>
  </select>

  <p>Your Selected Awrad will be shown here.</p>

  <!--Custom Div-->

  <div style="width: 200px;height: 100px;border: 2px green solid;border-radius: 5px;" id="div-j">

    <h4 id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></h4>
    <p id="clicks" style="text-align: center;"></p>


  </div>


  <!--Custom Div Ends-->


  <br>
  <!--<p id="clicks"></p><br>-->











  <img src="https://mb.burhaniya.pk/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/counter.png" onClick="onClick()" width="70" height="70" />
  <!--<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>-->





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you also tell me how can i refresh the to "0" counter without refresh the page

Comment: with a button or somehting